# Using Adobe Indesign for scientific writing

Tags: adobe-indesign

For the last years I had a somehow cumbersome and inefficient workflow to write and layout scientific papers. I wrote them in Mellel or MS Word due to the structure/ouline functionality and exported the text to finally doing layout in Indesign. So my question is: are there plugins for indesign that provide a structure/outline view, so one can navigate easyily to different chapters and managing the hierarchy of chapters?

Comment: For the record, your workflow is the standard for academic publications (well, that or use LaTeX, primarily in natural sciences). There isn’t really a better way. As long as you make sure to set up your Word/Mellel/Whatever document in a consistent way and use paragraph and character styles for everything instead of a lot of manual overrides, getting it to look right in InDesign can be a fairly straightforward and quick task.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Indesign has a **built in** [Story Editor](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-using-the-story-editor-in-indesign-cs5--vector-4610), [2](https://creativepro.com/hidden-gems-the-story-editor/), [3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/adobe_indesign_cc/adobe_indesign_cc_story_editor.htm). No need for any plugins, at least for the basics.

The Story Editor allows you to see content separated from the actual layout formatting.

I can't, in all confidence, state this may fill your specific needs entirely. However, it is something you should explore before looking to any third party items.

Comment: The Story Editor isn’t really comparable to the structure/outline view in Word or Mellel, which gives you a quick overview of all headings, etc., and allow you to easily jump back and forth between them, similar to the overview links in a Wikipedia article (but as a panel, rather than a list at the top of the document). It has its uses, but it doesn’t help with what Madamadam is asking about here.